# What is the best way to uninstall gems from a rails3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, uninstallation, bundler

I installed all of my gems using bundler via the Gemfile. I thought (mistakenly) that if I deleted a gem from my Gemfile and ran 'bundle install' that the deleted gems would be uninstalled. I've looked at the bundler help file and, so far as I can tell, it does not have a way to uninstall gems.

Do I just use gem uninstall x for everything? Is this going to confuse bundler?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Bundler is launched from your app's root directory so it makes sure all needed gems are present to get your app working.If for some reason you no longer need a gem you'll have to run the

```
    gem uninstall gem_name
```

as you stated above.So every time you run bundler it'll recheck dependencies

EDIT - 24.12.2014

I see that people keep coming to this question I decided to add a little something.
The answer I gave was for the case when you maintain your gems global. Consider using a gem manager such as rbenv or rvm to keep sets of gems scoped to specific projects.

This means that no gems will be installed at a global level and therefore when you remove one from your project's Gemfile and rerun bundle then it, obviously, won't be loaded in your project. Then, you can run bundle clean (with the project dir) and it will remove from the system all those gems that were once installed from your Gemfile (in the same dir) but at this given time are no longer listed there.... long story short -  it removes unused gems.

Answer (score 102):

This will uninstall a gem installed by bundler:

```
bundle exec gem uninstall GEM_NAME
```

Note that this throws

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method `delete' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:0x00000101142268>

but the gem is actually removed. Next time you run `bundle install` the gem will be reinstalled.

Comment: For RVM users: you have to use this method if you've set up a gemset for your particular project.  Running `gem uninstall pg` from the project folder will uninstall pg from your global/system level gemset instead of bundler's

Comment: Is this the error you're referring to? `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method \`delete' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:0x00000101142268>`

Comment: +1 for doing it in bundle context. wish it didn't throw that error! better yet, wish i could bundle -f update gemname.

Comment: @EricHu not if you are using the RVM gemset. whenever you install a gem with gem install xxx inside a RVM gemset, there is where it stays, so doing a plain gem uninstall xxx on a RVM gemset will remove the gem installed on that gemset and not the system one.

Comment: @EstebanFeldman you're right, I think this was a change made to RVM in the last 11 months.

Comment: Great, also works if gems are installed on a per-app basis without RVM. e.g. when gems are installed under `myapp/vendor` via the `bundle install --path vendor` command. Good for starting with a clean slate after some local debugging and hacking of 3rd party gems.

Answer (score 25):

With newer versions of bundler you can use the clean task:

```
$ bundle help clean
Usage:
    bundle clean

Options:
    [--dry-run=only print out changes, do not actually clean gems]
    [--force=forces clean even if --path is not set]
    [--no-color=Disable colorization in output]
    -V, [--verbose=Enable verbose output mode]

Cleans up unused gems in your bundler directory
$ bundle clean --dry-run --force
Would have removed actionmailer (3.1.12)
Would have removed actionmailer (3.2.0.rc2)
Would have removed actionpack (3.1.12)
Would have removed actionpack (3.2.0.rc2)
Would have removed activemodel (3.1.12)
...
```

edit:

This is not recommended if you're using a global gemset (i.e. - all of your projects keep their gems in the same place).
There're few ways to keep each project's gems separate, though:

1. `rvm` gemsets (http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)
2. `bundle install` with any of the following options: `--deployment` or `--path=<path>` (http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html)

Comment: Using `bundle clean --force` removed a bunch of gems that I don't use in my current project but do use in my other projects. Was I supposed to set a path? Just `bundle clean` returns "Can only use bundle clean when --path is set or --force is set". But the `--path` option doesn't even appear in the help.

Comment: That's correct @Dennis. The `clean` task doesn't really make sense if you're using a global gemset. But if you want, each of your projects can have its gems separate. You can do so either via rvm gemsets (http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics), or by specifying the gems' path through the `--path` option of `bundle install` (http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

Bundler now has a `bundle remove GEM_NAME` command (since [v1.17.0, 25 October 2018](https://bundler.io/blog/2018/10/25/announcing-bundler-1-17-0.html)).

Comment: This command only removes the gem from the Gemfile, it doesn't uninstall the gem from the system. If you want to uninstall it as well you'd want to run `bundle remove --install GEM_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

You must use 'gem uninstall gem_name' to uninstall a gem.

Note that if you installed the gem system-wide (ie. sudo bundle install) then you may need to specify the binary directory using the -n option, to ensure binaries belonging to the gem are removed. For example

```
sudo gem uninstall gem_name  -n /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to solve this by manually removing the unicorn gem via bundler ("sudo bundler exec gem uninstall unicorn"), then rebundling ("sudo bundle install").

Not sure why it happened though, although the above fix does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean up all your gems and start over

```
sudo gem clean
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Comment out your entire Gemfile
2. `bundle clean`

Done.