# How to uninstall all gems installed using `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How can I remove all the gems installed using `bundle install` in a particular RoR project. I don't want to uninstall gems that are used by other projects.

Comment: See: [What is the best way to uninstall gems from a rails3 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667150/what-is-the-best-way-to-uninstall-gems-from-a-rails3-project)

Answer (score 40):

Since we're using ruby you could do something like this I guess:

```
bundle list | ruby -e 'ARGF.readlines[1..-1].each {|l| g = l.split(" ");  puts "Removing #{g[1]}"; `gem uninstall --force #{g[1]} -v #{g[2].gsub(/\(|\)/, "")}`; }'
```

NOTE: Only lightly tested.

Comment: Tried this, and does not work. My hint is that the bundle list output is not a clean list of the specific gems: the gems in the bundle list do not include the version, there are bullet points and another header string that may be getting in the way. My two cents.

Comment: Worked for me after removing `--force`

Comment: for me on OSX worked with above except replacing `list` in first command with `show`. - wait - i'm not totally sure if it only uninstalled the gems from this particular Gemfile. It looks like it is: http://bundler.io/v1.11/bundle_show.html

Comment: Worked for me. Note, it also removes bundler so you need to `gem install bundler` then `bundle install`.

Comment: Worked out on a Fedora 31, but @martincito anwer using `rvm gemset empty` is far more efficient and clean.

Answer (score 29):

Comment out all gems in your Gemfile and run

```rb
bundle clean --force
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 18):

There's no one simple way to remove all gems - let alone removing those within a specific bundle. You could try some of these suggestions:
[Uninstall all installed gems, in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx)

Adapt to the `bundle show` command instead of `gem list`

---

For the future, try this approach:

If you install your bundle locally like the example below, the gems won't be installed in your global gem directory. Then you can easily delete the installation folder to delete all gems of the bundle.

```
# install gems to project_root/vendor/bundle
bundle install --path vendor/bundle --without test
```

The path option is saved to .bundle/config just like all others and any subsequent `bundle install` calls will use it unless you set it to something else or remove it from the config!

Comment: +1 I always install them in vendor. It's easier to manage and keep your system clean.

Comment: @KappaNossi : If I delete the folder. Would that free up the memory occupied by gems installed in the corresponding bundle?

Comment: Yes of course. The downside is only that if multiple projects use the same gem, you will have multiple installations of it in the corresponding vendor folders instead of using one central gem in the global gem list.

Answer (score 15):

You can use (like Tobias says, if you are using RVM)

`rvm gemset empty [gemset]`

Directly on the gemset, for example

```
rvm gemset empty 2.0.0@server
```

Answer (score 13):

It is actually as simple as

```
gem list --no-versions | xargs gem uninstall -a
```

If you are not using RVM/RBENV, you might hit into issue when gem attempts to uninstall system library which can fail. In that case, call uninstall command one by one to skip these.

```
gem list --no-versions | xargs -n1 gem uninstall -a
```

Comment: Love this solution. Easy, clean, faster than removing Ruby versions and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using rvm, you could of course just uninstall and reinstall the version of ruby under which you've installed the gems, i.e.

```
% rvm use
Using /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
% rvm uninstall 2.2.1
ruby-2.2.1 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.2.1..
ruby-2.2.1 - #removing default ruby interpreter.............
% rvm install 2.2.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/14.0/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.2.1 - #configure
ruby-2.2.1 - #download
ruby-2.2.1 - #validate archive
ruby-2.2.1 - #setup 
ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset created /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
ruby-2.2.1 - #importing gemset /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems..............................
ruby-2.2.1 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset created /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
ruby-2.2.1 - #importing gemsetfile /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.2.1 - #generating default wrappers........
```

and now you have a ruby environment clean of any installed gems.

Answer (score 4):

Another way from https://makandracards.com/jan0sch/9537-uninstall-all-ruby-gems-from-your-system (similar to [rainkinz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385516/539149) and [Ralph's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384664/how-to-uninstall-all-gems-installed-using-bundle-install#comment64794148_21385516)).  Here are some variations:

```
# if you're the root user:
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs -I % gem uninstall -aIx %

# if you're a non-root user:
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs -I % sudo gem uninstall -aIx %

# docker compose (if your service is named "web" running the root user):
docker-compose run web bash -c 'gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs -I % gem uninstall -aIx %'

####

gem install bundler
# or if using docker compose:
docker-compose run web gem install bundler

# optionally reinstall gems:
bundle install
# or if using docker compose:
docker-compose run web bundle install
```

Breaking this down:

- `gem list` lists all gems
- `cut -d" " -f1` takes the first column
- `xargs -I % gem uninstall -aIx %` calls `gem uninstall -aIx` with each output line as an argument

Note that I specified the argument with `-I` as `%` and passed it directly for security:

```
xargs -I % gem uninstall -aIx %
```

instead of:

```
xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

That's because `xargs` has a security issue where options like `-n` can be passed to its command and cause unexpected results.  This can be demonstrated with the following example:

```
# correctly prints "-n hello" (with trailing newline):
echo '-n Hello' | xargs -I % echo % | xargs -I % echo %

# incorrectly prints "hello" (without trailing newline):
echo '-n Hello' | xargs echo
```

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is similar to mine, then you want to uninstall all gems that were installed while testing `GemFile` changes, in that case I simply used:

```
bundle clean
```

That uninstalled all the gems that are not specified in the `GemFile` and `GemFile.lock`.

I have not tested it but I suppose you could delete all lines from your Gemfile and run the above command to get rid of all the gems installed by the ROR project in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I was using a `docker` setup and here's how I've reverted gems installed by `bundler` without rebuilding `docker`.

---

Have a back up copy of `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

Temporarily delete the contents of your `Gemfile` (**do not delete the file, just leave it blank**) then (**optionally**) delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run:

```
bundle clean --force
```

That should remove all gems installed by `bundler`.

Then you can revert `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` with your backup copy or `git`.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for uninstalling all gems except of default:

Crete delete_gems.rb with

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Remove all gems EXCEPT defaults :)

`gem list -d`.split(/\n\n^(?=\w)/).each do |data|
  match = data.match(/(?<name>([^\s]+)) \((?<versions>.*)\)/)
  name = match[:name]
  versions = match[:versions].split(', ')

  if match = data.match(/^.*\(([\d\.]*),? ?default\): .*$/)
    next if match[1].empty? # it's the only version if this match is empty
    versions.delete(match[1] || versions[0])
  end

  versions.each { |v| system "gem uninstall -Ix #{name} -v #{v}" }
end
```

Run this script:

```
sudo chmod 1777 delete_gems.rb
./delete_gems.rb
```

All gems will be removed except of default.
Here link on original solution
http://zanshin.net/2013/06/10/how-to-delete-all-ruby-gems/

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you could use rvm. To list all available gemsets

```
rvm gemset list
```

And then

```
rvm gemset empty <gemset-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
rm -rf vendor/bundle/
```

Of if you're the timid type:

```
mv vendor/bundle vendor/bundle_old
```

Simple, easy, and guaranteed to flush out the cruft.