# Uninstall all installed gems in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

First, I did not use rvm or rbenv. I want to uninstall every gem in my Rails project and then bundle from the beginning. Gem installation directory is pointing to my global directory so I can't just delete that one.

In modern Javascript projects, you can simply `rm -rf node_modules` and npm/yarn install instantly, is there a similar way in Rails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall all gems installed using \`bundle install\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384664/how-to-uninstall-all-gems-installed-using-bundle-install)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384664/how-to-uninstall-all-gems-installed-using-bundle-install)

This answer is probably best in your case:

```
gem list --no-versions | xargs gem uninstall -a
```

Comment: if it's a dupe, either vote-to-close as a dupe, or if you don't have enough rep, leave a comment stating such.

Comment: @Joe got the rep and voted thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, rvm or rbenv are useful, consider using one of them.

You're using bundle, so if you want to make sure your command line only use the gems indicated in your Gemfile, you can just add "bundle exec your_command", like `bundle exec rails s`. So, it might be unnecessary to delete all the gems.

If you want to save place, my best advice would be to empty your global directory, use rbenv or rvm :)

Comment: the user is not use rvm or rbenv so stop telling them they should. This is not an answer.